# Phone soft reboots when making or receiving a call [Nexus 6][CM13]

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-6, t-mobile, soft-reboot

I've got a pretty severe bug that results in my phone soft rebooting every time I try to make a phone call or a phone call would be coming in on the main number.

What I did to try to fix (no luck):

1. Downloaded latest snapshot: https://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/158646/cm-13.0-20160418-SNAPSHOT-ZNH0EAO2NL-shamu.zip
2. Downloaded latest gapps for 6.0: http://opengapps.org/ (ARM 6.0 Stock package)
3. Wiped /system, /data, dalvik cache & /cache
4. Installed #1 and #2
5. Wiped /internal storage
6. Updating radio/bootloader to latest available

What's going on? This just started manifesting after I did a `cm13Nighty (4-11-2016)` > `cm13Snapshot (4-18-2016)` upgrade. I would've thought the reset would fix it at least?

---

Other things I've tried with no luck:

1. Disabling/enabling WiFi Calling
2. Booting into Safe Mode
3. Deleting `com.android.providers.x` folders in `/data/data` & wiped Dalvik/cache again (This fixed WiFi calling consequently - *dysfunctional again after soft-crash* - *interesting...*)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is the current build of `gapps` - quick workaround is to manually set the `Phone/Dialer` app as the default `Phone App` in <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Apps</kbd> -> [image] -> <kbd>Default Apps</kbd> -> <kbd>Phone App</kbd>.

Source: https://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/124381-dialer-crashes/?do=findComment&comment=590388